# Ping webserver when iphone app loads

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I was wondering how I could ping a web server of mine when my application first starts. I am assuming I would do s via the appdelegate in the application? Is there any specific example I could use?

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem actually? You want to know whether Internet and/or your server is available or you want to know when to ping it? If you want to know the network or host status then you can use [Reachability sample app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) by Apple. This Rechability class is widely used.